# Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<User, void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, void>'

Tags: angular, api

Hi I am new to angular and I am trying to learn how to interact with API'S but in my code, I am getting the following error when trying to return information from the key.

**Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<FlickrOutput, void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, void>**

From looking into the issue I have seen people solve it by making sure this is imported - import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; That did not solve the issue.

```
export interface FlickrPhoto {
  farm: string;
  id: string;
  secret: string;
  server: string;
  title: string;
}

export interface FlickrOutput {
  photos: {
    photo: FlickrPhoto[];
  };
}


search_keyword(keyword: string) {
  
    const url = 'https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&';
    const params = `api_key=${environment.flickr.key}&text=${keyword}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&per_page=12&page=${this.currPage}`;

    return this.http.get(url + params).pipe(
      map((res: FlickrOutput ) => {
(I am getting the error here in res :flickrOutpu)

      
     }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: .... `return this.http.get<FlickrOutput>(url + params).pipe( ... `  ??

Comment: yes that fixed. Is the error caused because it did not know there was an interface?

Comment: Hi @Vovan_Super, please add the solution as **answer** since it helps Post Owner. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, with versions of typescript and Angular grow, there's tendency of stuff going stricter (see tsconfig's `compilerOptions` strict configs (and, btw, `angularCompilerOptions`s `strictTemplates` param, making stricter checks in your Tempalates), introduction of `HttpClient` with ts-generics compared to 'old' Http module in Angular 2);
Hence the error, kinda , is about the following: having the code :

```js
return this.http.get(url + params).pipe(
      map((res: FlickrOutput ) => { /// ...
```

you rather have the following :

```js
return this.http.get<Object>(url + params).pipe(
      map((res: FlickrOutput ) => { // type get request to type `object` or kinda, `any`, and due to strict type-checking warns : "`get` method returns Object, but you claim the `res` response to be of type `FlickrOutput` - but they are different (not implicitly "convertible") types ... "
```

to type request with generic of your interface: `this.http.get<FlickrOutput>(url + params).pipe( ...`